# How can we prove that this integral converges?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

If we have integral in the form $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(r+a \exp (-xt) )]\sqrt{(1+(a \exp (-xt))^2)}} \ dt $ and if we take difference of such two integrals with the same $r>0$ and different (or the same) $a>0$ and $x>0$ in this two integrals, this difference will converge. See example on Picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOmHe.png). Can we prove that?

I really can't understand why integral on Picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOmHe.png) does converge but integral on Picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tze64.png) doesn't. Looking at the antiderivative on Picture [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxAhR.png) no idea why is that happens. Could you help please?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

Comment: Hint: look at the integrand for  $t\to+\infty$. For $x>0$ the integrand goes to $\frac{1}{r}$ for $t\to+\infty$, hence the integral diverges. For $x\lt0$ the integrand behaves as $\frac{1}{a} e^{-|x| t} $ and the integral is convergent.

Comment: In the difference of the two integrands the constant terms cancel, and you are left with integrable terms.

Comment: Replace the difference of the two intergrals by one intergral over the difference of the integrands. Start with intergrals with a finite upper limit A, take the difference of these, transfer the difference to the integrand  and only in the end take the limit $A\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

We derive the exact expression for the integral.

The integral in question is

$$f = \int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{(a \exp (-x t))^2+1} (a \exp (-x y)+r)} \, dt$$

First let us have a look at the convergence of the integral. For $x\gt 0$ the integrand goes to $\frac{1}{r}$ for $t\to+\infty$, hence the integral diverges. For $x\lt0$ the integrand behaves as $(\frac{1}{a} e^{-|x| t})^2 $ and the integral is convergent.

Hence we assume $x\lt0$. Letting $y=-x>0$ and substituting $t\to \frac{1}{y} \log(u)$, $dt \to \frac{du}{u y}$, $t\in(0,\infty) \to u\in(1,\infty)$ the integral becomes

$$f=\frac{1}{y} \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{ u \sqrt{a^2 u^2+1} (a u+r)}\,du$$

Mathematica finds

$$f = \frac{1}{y} \frac{\sqrt{r^2+1} \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2+1}+1}{a}\right)+\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\left(a^2+1\right) \left(r^2+1\right)}+a r-1}{a+r}\right)-\sinh ^{-1}(r)}{r \sqrt{r^2+1}}$$

Comment: Ok, but I'm interested only in the case of $x>0$ and difference between such two integrals as shown on Picture 1. Also, about first part of your proof: how can we estimate convergence through integrand? Shouldn't we investigate limits for antiderivative instead?

Comment: Consider the much simpler example: $i_1=\int_0^\infty \frac{  1}{1+x}$ and $i_2=\int_0^\infty \frac{  1}{2+x}$. Each integral is divergent but the difference can be given a meaning by integrating the difference of the integrands which converges.

Comment: Still can't understand how to show this more rigorous with proper math.

Comment: Sorry, but I have descibed here in several occasions how you can transform your question into proper math. Your $\infty - \infty$ surely is not "proper math".